# React Redux, my component is not connected to Redux Store. I tested the action and reducer in another component, it does work for other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

The flow is like this:

1. Click on `CarouselItem`, which trigger the `onClick={this.handleId}`.
2. `handleId` takes the id, which is a prop of the clicked `CarouselItem`
3. `this.props.dispatch(fetchRecon(movieId));` will make an AJAX action, which will return data
4. and within the Redux state, set a property that initially is `moviesRecon:[]` to `moviesRecon:[data]`. `handleId` will also route me to a new page using `` this.props.history.push(`/movie-detail?query=${movieId}`); ``
5. I should now be on the component `MovieDetailPage`, which is currently using mock data for the `Carousel` component. Ideally, I should be passing `this.props.moviesRecon` for the movies prop of `Carousel`.

Attempting to do so gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
 const carousel = this.props.movies.map((item, index) => {
| ^  51 |         return (
  52 |             <CarouselItem data={item} index={index} key={this.props.movies[index].id} id={this.props.movies[index].id} />
  53 |         );
```

Here are the components that I think are relevant:
CarouselItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './CarouselItem.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchRecon } from '../../actions/index';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export class CarouselItem extends React.Component{

    handleId = e => {
        let movieId = this.props.id
        console.log("carousel item", movieId);
        this.props.dispatch(fetchRecon(movieId));
        this.props.history.push(`/movie-detail?query=${movieId}`);


    }

    render() {

        let genres = this.props.genres;
        let genreList = this.props.genres.length;

        function getGenreText(id) {
            for (let i = 0; i < genreList; i++) {
                if (genres[i].id == id) {
                    return genres[i].name;
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.props.data) {
            return (
                <div className="movieContainer" onClick={this.handleId}>
                    <img className="moviePoster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.props.data.poster_path}`} alt={this.props.data.title} />
                    <h3 className="movieName">{this.props.data.title}</h3>
                    <p className="movieGenre">{getGenreText(this.props.data.genre_ids[0])}</p>
                </div>

            );
        }   
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    genres: state.app.genres
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(CarouselItem));
```

Carousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CarouselItem from '../CarouselItem/CarouselItem';
import './Carousel.css';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export class Carousel extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // the trick
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 50);
  }
    render(){


        console.log("carousel probs", this.props);
        const carousel = this.props.movies.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <CarouselItem data={item} index={index} key={this.props.movies[index].id} id={this.props.movies[index].id} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="inner-carousel">
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                <Slider {...settings}>
                    {carousel}
                </Slider>
                <hr className="carousel-divider"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

MovieDetailPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Carousel } from '../Carousel/Carousel';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {fetchRecon} from '../../actions/index';
import { recommended } from './mock';
import { movieDetails } from './mockdetails';
import './MovieDetailPage.css';

export class MovieDetailPage extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        window.onpopstate = () => {
            const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
            const clickedMovie = params.get("query");
            console.log('here', clickedMovie);
        }
        const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
        const movieId = params.get("query");
        console.log('here', movieId);

        // this.props.dispatch(fetchRecon(movieId));
    }


    render() {
        console.log('movie detail', this.props.moviesRecon, this.props)
        return (
            <div className="movieDetail">
                <div className="movieDetail-container">
                    <img className="movieDetail-bg" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/or06FN3Dka5tukK1e9sl16pB3iy.jpg`} />
                </div>
                <div className="main-details">
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
                    <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={this.props.moviesRecon} />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLoading: state.app.isLoading,
    moviesRecon: state.app.moviesRecon
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(MovieDetailPage));
```

For MovieDetailPage.js on line 29 I am logging the following in the console:

```
movie detail undefined 
{history: {…}, location: {…}, match: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
history: {length: 17, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/movie-detail", search: "?query=456740", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "dyth5r"}
match: {path: "/movie-detail", url: "/movie-detail", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Reducers.js, if necessary, but I have already confirmed the action, and reducer are correctly setting the state, as other components are able to access moviesRecon.

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading: 0,
    genres: [],
    moviesPlaying: [],
    moviesPopular: [],
    moviesUpcoming: [],
    moviesTop: [],
    movieSearch:[],
    moviesRecon: [],
    searchTerm: ""

};

export const Reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type === FETCH_RECON_SUCCESS) {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            moviesRecon: action.recon
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wrote you an answer friend! Let me know if that helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. I basically wrote my import wrong in my higher level App.js component, that's why it wasn't being connected. I was attempting to import a member of the MovieDetailPage named MovieDetailPage and not the default export, which was the connected component I needed. So a typo...

I had `{ MovieDetailPage }` and it should be `MovieDetailPage`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error due to this line,

```
 <Carousel title={"Recommended"} movies={recommended} />
```

You are passing a component `recommended`, which I can see is imported in your case, using `import { recommended } from './mock';`.

In the `Carousel` component you are trying to iterate over the `movies` array using `map`.

This is why you are getting error, because `recommended` is a `component` and **not** a `array`.

Try to pass `array` to all your child component's.

Comment: It's unclear whether it's actually a component though. recommended could very likely be an array.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Try to comment all other child component which are using `recommended` and see if your code works.

Comment: Oh my mistake for not clarifying, the component `recommended` is mock data, which I am using to see if the component is failing because of the component itself. Which it is not. It is `movies={this.props.moviesRecon}` that is failing. And that is because I believe the component is not connected to the Redux Store for some reason.

Comment: @Kaleidics  But what is the mock data. Is it an array []. Or an object {}? Or an actual component?

Comment: The mock data is an array of objects. Commenting out 
`movies={this.props.moviesRecon}`, and the application will run using the mock data and I will have 5 `Carousels` displayed on the dom. However, commenting out the `Carousel` with mock data, and leaving in `movies={this.props.moviesRecon}` and the app will crash.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo

Answer (score 0):

I think you initiate your `.map` before your component has enough time to obtain the movies data. You can do the following to check for that:

**Carousel.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import CarouselItem from '../CarouselItem/CarouselItem'
import './Carousel.css'
import Slider from 'react-slick'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'
export class Carousel extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // the trick
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.forceUpdate()
    }, 50)
  }

  createCarousels = () => {
    const movies = this.props.movies

    if (movies.length > 0) {
      return movies.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <CarouselItem
            data={item}
            index={index}
            key={this.props.movies[index].id}
            id={this.props.movies[index].id}
          />
        )
      })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="inner-carousel">
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>{this.createCarousels()}</Slider>
        <hr className="carousel-divider" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

On a side-note, it looks like you're trying to spread the `settings` object into your `Slider` component, but you never defined settings anyway. Should look into that.

Comment: I did not include the settings for readability reasons. But I just tried your solution and I got 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
`if (movies.length > 0) {`


Which comes back to the same problem, it doesn't look like MovieDetailPage.js is getting the Redux Store. And, therefore when it passes it as props to carousel. this.props is being `undefined`.